# Proof that the sample mean is normally distributed

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, sample

I am studying the book of [Larsen and Marx](https://www.amazon.de/INTRO-MATHEMATICAL-STATISTI-Richard-Larsen-dp-0134114213/dp/0134114213/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) and stumbled upon

[image: Corollary 4.3.1]

I can prove that $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}$ and $Var(\bar{Y})=\frac{\sigma ^{2}}{n}$ but how would I go to show that $\bar{Y}$ is normally distributed? Why normal? Should I use the Normal MGF?

Comment: For more answers, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22linear+combination%22+normal+score%3A2).

Comment: I did but none of the questions answers mine

Comment: Use the first link about a linear combination of random normal variables, then use induction.

Comment: They all answer this question, because $\bar Y$ is a linear combination of the $Y_i$ with coefficients $1/n.$

Comment: @whuber I understand this but why should the distrubution of  $\bar{Y}$ be normal? How do you prove normality of the resulting distribution?

Comment: Base case of the induction: use MGFs to show that  $aY_1+bY_2$ is normal. Inductive step: show that if $Y_{n-1}$ is normal, then $cY_{n-1}+dY_n$ is normal, again by using the MGFs.

Comment: @Dave . Thanks I thought so. Still it would be nice to have an answer based on MGFs as you propose.

Comment: The answers in the duplicates are all based on the mgfs or their equivalents (cfs or cgfs).